# Can I know when/where is the Runnale task submitted when debugging multi-thread project,IntelliJ

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I am currently working on a project which maintans several thread pools. And there are many communication between each threads. For example, when I finish a task from pool1, I will signal pool 2 to wakeup to pickup some new task.

Always ,  I try to figure out "who post this task " to this pool2, so that I can trace back to the source.

But if I put a breakpoint inside the task `run()`, I will have a stack trace like:

[image]

which starts from the call method from `Executors`, which is not enough for me to easily look into what happens.

Actually, I hope I konw where it is submited(this sometimes may be at another class):

```
this.brokerController.getPullMessageExecutor().submit(run);
```

This is this most important statement when I need to debugging.

Typically, I will have to follw the below steps:

1. Put a debug point inside a method
2. Trace back to the Runnale Task
3. Find usage of this Runnale class, find who creates the instance of it.(If I am unlucky, I will find several places who creates tasks)
4. Look into the code aroud 3, find where to submit the task to.

This may be a painful process, Is there any way or plugin to easily find the task soure?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are creating a thread pool by Executors?

Comment: @pbajpai21, my problem is not about code. My problem is sometimes I don't know where should I look into when a task is running. So for most of the case , I may even not easily find where is the thread pool and who submit tasks to it.

Comment: There can be no thread of control that started a particular task, because a thread might be just waiting to read form a queue to which you post your message. The easiest way to track messages would be to include the tracking information inside them. This is what e.g. IP packets on the internet do.

Comment: @Jaskey, thats why I just asked you for the code where you are creating thread pool...so that I will also try to debug at my end...may be We can find then...

Comment: @9000 , I am new to this project , so I am now currently working on how thoes threads commuicate, how can I not know the logic and trace it? Most of the case, when I get a open-source project, we will follow the debug point to figure it out what happens, but this will do little use on multi-thread project since they always signal the other thread.

Comment: @Jaskey: I would start from looking at the thread pool, the ways to activate threads / submit jobs to it; maybe there's a convenient spot to add a conditional breakpoint that wakes up only when a particular type of a task is submitted. Also, adding copious logging statements around the functions you want to understand often helps when debugging is impossible or breaks things by the fact of intervention — for instance, when debugging pauses a thread so much that the task is considered timed out, etc.